# How to use variable inside the parameter of $_POST in php

Tags: php, post

I will be getting some certain amount of data. I will get the number for which the for loop to be run.

For example
I get the number 3 and I will get three parameters like par1,par2 and par3 then how should I pass this `par1` in the `$_post`

like

```
 $i=$_POST["number"];
 for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
 {

   $par.$i = $_POST["par".$i];

 }
```

Here I cant get the value from `$_POST["par".$i]`;
As it is not able to get the variable inside the paramater of `$_POST`

Any help will be thankful

Comment: Hi @Parth: I updated my answer according to your need. It's working for me. Apply It and respond me back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you create a new array `$par` and there you will put by index all the par you will have like this:

```
$i=$_POST["number"];
$par = [];
 for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
 {

   $par[$i] = $_POST["par".$i];

 }
```

After that if you want to go throw all pars you can simply use `foreach` like this:

```
foreach($par as $key => $value) {
  // $key will be 1,2,3
  // $value will be the value from $_POST["par" . $i]
}
```

The `.` is to concatenate two strings in PHP, and you can't create a new variable like you tried. If you want to have in `$par1`, `$par2` and `$par3` you can do like this:

```
${"par" . $i} = $_POST["par".$i];
```

But I don't recommend this way because it's more hard to handle.

Answer (score 0):

***One Way***

According to your question.

```
<?php
$n = $_POST["number"];
$par = "par";
for($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++){
    $par.$i = $_POST["par".$i];
}?>
```

***Alternative Way***

In this scenario,

> For example I get the number 3 and I will get three parameters like
>   par1,par2 and par3 then how should I pass this par1 in the $_post.

Better, make 'par' input name as an array type as 'par[]' (`<input type='text' name='par[]'>`) in your file instead using par1, par2 .. par(n).

And, no need to worry in submit page.

```
<?php
$n = $_POST["number"];
for($i=1;$i<= $n;$i++){
  $newPar = $_POST["par"][$i];
  // Write here your logic to use how you want.
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Nana
I tried the way one which you have posted 
that works for me but the for loop runs for only one time
like I get the value of first parameter only not for the second and third

Comment: See, best way to approach 2nd way (alternative way) which I posted as answer. See it. It will make your work more easier. @ParthDhorda

Comment: If you EDIT your question with full code, work will be more easier to guide you towards solution. @ParthDhorda

Comment: If this answer helped you @ParthDhorda, Please don't forget to mark this answer as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find it easily. Thanks. *Happy To Help*