# Is it possible to put a php variable inside $_POST['']?

Tags: php

I was wondering if it's possible to put a PHP variable inside `$_POST['']` like this:

```
$_POST[$variable];
```

I'm asking this because I have a page in which all the inputs have dynamic names according to how many orders the user has made and when I must retrieve their values through post, I never know the names but if I would have something like `$_POST[$variable]` I would know. The variable is a string and so it would turn out like `$_POST['String']`.

So is it possible to do something like this?

```
$numero = $count_ficha;
$countU = 1;

for ($i = 1;$i < $numero + 1;$i++) {
    $identificador = "identificadorNI".$countU;
    $identificador2 = "identificador".$countU;
    $id_subencomenda = $_POST[$identificador];
    $countU++;

    echo $id_subencomenda;
}
```

Comment: It's possible.. But since you will define the value for `$variable`, what's the difference?

Comment: Yes, it is possible but you still have to assign a value.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Maybe `foreach($_POST as $field => $value) {` would be useful for you.

Comment: Sounds like there could be security implications

Comment: Yes i tried and nothing happened, i assumed it was because it didnt work. Also the variable's content will be constantly changing since it's in a loop.

Comment: I edited the question so you can see the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use variable inside the parameter of $\_POST in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386033/how-to-use-variable-inside-the-parameter-of-post-in-php)

Comment: If the form fields are related, use arrays. [How to get form input array into PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use a variable inside `$_POST['']` such as `$_POST[$variable]`

You will still be required, however, to define a value for `$variable`

Comment: Why the down vote for this answer? It is technically correct. I only ask so that I can better understand what my error is...

Answer (score 0):

It is posible, but if you don't know the key of $POST[] that you're trying to get the value of, how could you know what value that you have to put on $variable?

For unknow values, the best you can do is a foreach, so you can iterate all the $*POST array and then you can do whatever you want with the values, like this*

```
foreach ($_POST as $key) {
   //do whatever you want with the $key
}
```

Check [PHP foreach](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score -1):

if you have a dynamic value for the page you just use some $variable because $_POST is use to send information from some HTTP POST method.

(http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

maybe you can resolve your problem by creating a global variable.